# Error Grouping in Pivot MySQL with Join Table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have non aggregate rows data in MySQL and I need to create a pivot.

I run my query:

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.kredit_member_no,
  CASE WHEN b.slug='fullname' THEN a.value END as fullname,
  CASE WHEN b.slug='gender' THEN a.value END as gender,
  CASE WHEN b.slug='email' THEN a.value END as email
FROM kredit_data a
LEFT JOIN master_data b ON a.master_id = b.id
WHERE b.slug = 'fullname'
  OR b.slug = 'gender'
  OR b.slug = 'email'
GROUP BY a.kredit_member_no;
```

But I get this MySQL Error:

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP
BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'vortunes_db.a.id' which
is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this
is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

And I remove the `GROUP BY` i get this result : 
[image]

How to group them by `kredit_member_no` ?

Answer (score 2):

Even though your data is a string, you'll still want to use an aggregate function on those `CASE` statements to pivot those rows into columns. Since [you have `only_full_group_by` turned on](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), you'll also need to either place `a.id` into the `GROUP BY` clause or you'll need to remove it that column from the final select list.  I'd suggest changing the query to this:

```
SELECT 
  a.kredit_member_no,
  max(CASE WHEN b.slug='fullname' THEN a.value END) as fullname,
  max(CASE WHEN b.slug='gender' THEN a.value END) as gender,
  max(CASE WHEN b.slug='email' THEN a.value END) as email
FROM kredit_data a
LEFT JOIN master_data b 
  ON a.master_id = b.id
  and b.slug IN ('fullname', 'gender', 'email')
GROUP BY a.kredit_member_no;
```

[See SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e31e/1/0)

You will also notice that I moved your `WHERE` clause to the JOIN, this is because you were basically performing an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`, which doesn't seem like what you intended.